# How to access Properties of Objects supplied to event handler? (Can view when debugging, but not with Intellisense.)

Tags: c#, listview

I am trying to find which item is selected in a `ListView`. When the selection is changed, I run the following code:

```
private void Change_CurrentConnection(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var d = e.AddedItems[0];
}
```

And you can see here what `d` is:
[image]

My question is, how can I access the `Id`, `Name`, and `Url` properties? (The properties are strings from a custom class. The `ListView` is bound to a collection of objects generated from that class.)

Comment: Casting is the answer. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to cast the item as your class, which appears to be called Connection?  You should first check to see if the object you are casting is actually of the type you wish to cast it to:

```
if (e.AddedItems[0] is Connection)
{
    Connection toAccess = e.AddedItems[0] as Connection;

    // Here you can access the properties directly
    string myUrl = toAccess.Url;
}
```

This way we avoid an InvalidCastException.

Comment: You should discuss what happens if the object being cast is not a `Connection`.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Excellent point.  I've edited the response to include checking validity of the cast.

Answer (score 1):

you can do this as the following also

```
Connection lstViewItem = (Connection)YourListView.SelectedItems[0];
```

Comment: What do you mean about conditional checks?

Comment: I mean to delete that comment but got distracted by work.. disregard the comment @JohnSaunders thanks I updated the answer to remove that comment