# How do I get the SelectedItem in a Listview with Listbox in it?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am having trouble getting the selecteditem from a listbox which is a child of a listview.  Everything that I've tried returns the GpoObject which is set at the parent listview, but not the selected OuLink from the Listbox.

This is my DataTemplate for the ListBox:

```
        <DataTemplate x:Key="OuTemplate">
            <Label Content="{Binding Path=Path}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
```

This is my Listview with the ListBox in it:

```
    <ListView x:Name="OutListView" 
              BorderBrush="#FFA0A0A0" 
              BorderThickness="1">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Group Policy Objects" 
                                Width="Auto">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" 
                                       Text="{Binding Path=Name}" 
                                       Width="Auto"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Organizational Units">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ListBox Grid.Column="1" 
                                     ItemsSource="{Binding Path=OUs}" 
                                     ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource OuTemplate}"  
                                     Width="Auto" Height="Auto" 
                                     BorderThickness="0"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Object for binding:

```
public class GpoObject 
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public List<OuLink> OUs { get; set; }


}

public class OuLink 
{
    public string Path { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: someone asked a similar question check out here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28683297/how-to-access-properties-of-objects-supplied-to-event-handler-can-view-when-de/28683448#28683448, if that does not help please do a google search there are tons of working examples here on `stackoverflow`

Comment: Where exactly do you want to get the selected item? Depending on the *location* of this need may lead to an appropriate answer.

Comment: @OmegaMan My plan was to allow the user to double click an item in the child listbox, and it return the path. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways to access the `Path` off of the ListBox selected item. I have named the listbox to make it easier in Xaml. To show the selected info I pathed to it in a textbox now which resides above the Listbox (see image):

```
<GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock x:Name="tbSelected"
                        Text="{Binding ElementName=PathBox, Path=SelectedItem.Path}" />
            <ListBox x:Name="PathBox"
                        SelectionChanged="PathBox_OnSelectionChanged"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=OUs}"
                        ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource OuTemplate}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
```

Then on when the selection changes I present the user with a message box of the selected path:

```
private void PathBox_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var lbi = sender as ListBox;
    if (lbi != null)
        if (lbi.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            var link = lbi.SelectedItem as OuLink;

            if (link != null)
                MessageBox.Show(link.Path);

        }
}
```

Here is a selection and its propagation to the textbox and the message box:
[image]

---

I suggest that within the `OnSelectionChanged` instead of a messagebox you place that selection into a `INotifyPropertyChanged` string property on your ViewModel and propagate it that way to other items within the program.

Comment: Thanks so much! This has been driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Add `SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedOuLink}"` to your ListBox in your xaml.

Then in your `GpoObject` class add:

```
public OuLink SelectedOuLink { get; set; }
```

You can now retrieve the selected `OuLink` object via `SelectedOuLink`.